# Вывести положительное число со знаком +

Tags: c#

Как это можно сделать, без "ручной" простановки знака +

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Самый простой путь — воспользоваться [*кастомным форматированием*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SectionSeparator):

```
var x = 4;
var s = x.ToString("+#;-#;0");
```

Три случая, разделённые `;`, отвечают числу больше нуля, меньше нуля и нулю. Если вы хотите, можно выводить и ноль со знаком: `"+#;-#;+0"`.

Если вы используете `string.Format`, сработает `string.Format("{0:+#;-#;+0}", x)`. Для интерполированных строк `$"{x:+#;-#;+0}"`.

---

Для второй секции нужен явный минус, т. к. в этом случае он убирается. Для третьей секции нужен `0` вместо `#`, т. к. `#` не учитывает *незначащие* нули.

Comment: Работает, но когда я применяю это к числу типа double пропадает дробная часть

Comment: @КириллКирьянчиков: Ага, это для `int`. Для `double` используйте `#.#` (или сколько вам нужно знаков после запятой). Или `0.0`, если нужна обязательно дробная часть, даже если число целое.

Comment: Работает как часики, спасибо.

Comment: @КириллКирьянчиков: Пожалуйста!